# WaitHandle is closed when it shouldn't have

Tags: c#, multithreading, waithandle

This code works, for most of time, so I'm thinking of some race condition. **Result** class is immutable, but I don't think the issue is with that class.

```
public Result GetResult()
{
    using (var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false))
    {
        Result result = null;

        var completedHandler = new WorkCompletedEventHandler((o, e) =>
        {
            result = e.Result;

            // somehow waitHandle is closed, thus exception occurs here
            waitHandle.Set();
        });
        try
        {
            this.worker.Completed += completedHandler;

            // starts working on separate thread
            // when done, this.worker invokes its Completed event
            this.worker.RunWork();

            waitHandle.WaitOne();

            return new WorkResult(result);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.worker.Completed -= completedHandler;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Apologies, I've missed a call to this.worker.RunWork() right before calling GetResult() method. This apparently resulted (sometimes) in doing same job twice, though I'm not sure why waitHandle got closed before **waitHandle.Set()**, despite having Completed event firing twice. This hasn't compromised the IO work at all (results *were correct*; after I've changed the code to manually close the **waitHandle**).

Therefore, [Iridium's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14103796/93944) should be closest answer (if not the right one), even though the question wasn't complete.

Comment: due to your using clause the waithandle has disposed already invoked. If you dispose the waithandle in your completed eventhandler you should be fine.

Comment: No, WaitHandle, in most cases, is disposed after the work is finished (see **waitHandle.WaitOne()** _after_ **this.worker.RunWork()**)

Comment: Well in that case you have to wait till somebody else comes up with an answer.

Comment: ReSharper gives a access to disposed closure error

Comment: See **waitHandle.WaitOne()** - waitHandle shouldn't get disposed (it should get disposed after waitHandle is signalled).

Comment: @mnn Why use a separate thread, if the main thread is waiting for it to complete?

Comment: That's not the main thread. And I'm using this approach, because the work is heavily IO-based, thus there's no point in straining HDD, by parallelising IO-work.

Comment: @mnn The thread calling the GetResult methods can go ahead and call worker.RunWork(). There is no need for you to spawn a new thread and make the thread calling GetResult wait for the spawned thread to return.

Comment: I don't follow why you're blocking one thread while executing work on another thread. As I understand it, the `GetResult()` function executes synchronously, doesn't it? So what's the point?

Comment: Jon B: Well, there's progress update behind scenes, but since that has no access to WaitHandle, which causes problems, I think it's not necessary to clutter question with that. Ganesh R.: As I said, it's IO-based, thus no need to torture HDD, when most of work is reading/writing data.

Comment: @mnn Why not just provide a sync method in Worker class say: RunWorkSync, which will only return with a result or throw an exception? This will simply your code and avoid the use of wait handles. Still if you want to use wait handles, use a wait handle that is at the global level. But then you will have to be careful if multiple threads subscribe to OnCompleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem anything particularly problematic in the code you've given, which would suggest that there is perhaps something in the code you've not shown that's causing the problem. I'm assuming that the `worker` you're using is part of your codebase (rather than part of the .NET BCL like `BackgroundWorker`?) It may be worth posting the code for that, in case there is an issue there that's causing the problem.

If for example, the same worker is used repeatedly from multiple threads (or has a bug in which `Completed` can be raised more than once for the same piece of work), then if the worker uses the "usual" means for invoking an event handler, i.e.:

```
var handler = Completed;
if (handler != null)
{
    handler(...);
}
```

You could have an instance where `var handler = Completed;` is executed *before* the `finally` clause (and so before the `completedHandler` has been detached from the `Completed` event), but `handler(...)` is called *after* the `using(...)` block is exited (and so after the `ManualResetEvent` has been disposed). Your event handler will then be executed after `waitHandle` is disposed, and the exception you are seeing will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

There is no obvious reason why this would fail from the posted code.  But we can't see a stack trace and we can't see the logic that gets the Completed event fired so there are few opportunities to debug this for you.  Arbitrarily, if the event fires more than once then you'll certainly have this kind of race problem.

Vexing threading problems are hard to debug, threading races are problems that occur at microsecond scale.  Trying to debug it can be enough to make the race disappear.  Or it happens so infrequently that having any hope of catching the problem is too rare to justify an attempt.

Such problems often require logging to diagnose the race. Be sure to select a light-weight logging method, logging in itself can alter the timing enough to prevent the race from ever occurring.

Last but certainly not least: do note that there is no point in using a thread here.  You get the *exact* same outcome by directly calling the code that's executed by whatever thread is started by RunWork().  Minus the overhead and the headaches.

Comment: See this comment - there's underlying progress update to GUI, thus separate thread is actually needed.  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103360/waithandle-is-closed-when-it-shouldnt-have/14103459#comment19512666_14103360

Comment: Well, what's the point if the UI thread is dead, stuck on the WaitOne() call.  Time to start looking at the BackgroundWorker class, designed to keep you out of trouble like this.

Comment: That's not UI thread, of course, it's background thread, which does the heavy work (worker is just a small portion of that). Edit: I actually used BackgroundWorker, but only for a small amount of time - I needed something different and a bit more complex.

Comment: If it is already a worker thread that calls WaitOne() then there is especially no point in starting yet another worker thread.  A worker thread that doesn't do any work is useless.

Answer (score 0):

If you get rid of the using your code will not throw an exception at the by you designated line...
You have to find a decent place to dispose it, if you really need to.

```
public Result GetResult()
{
    var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        Result result = null;

        var completedHandler = new WorkCompletedEventHandler((o, e) =>
        {
            result = e.Result;

            // somehow waitHandle is closed, thus exception occurs here
            waitHandle.Set();
            waitHandle.Dispose();
        });
        try
        {
            this.worker.Completed += completedHandler;

            // starts working on separate thread
            // when done, this.worker invokes its Completed event
            this.worker.RunWork();

            waitHandle.WaitOne();

            return new WorkResult(result);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.worker.Completed -= completedHandler;
        }
}
```

Comment: Well, what's more troubling is that, when exception is thrown on **waitHandle.Set()**, the other thread, that created **waitHandle** _is still waiting on_ **waitHandle.waitOne()**, thus using clause couldn't have disposed waitHandle by that point.

Comment: did you even bother to try this or are you only theoretical reasoning?

Comment: Yes, I know, it removes exception, however any exception thrown after waitHandle is created, which prevent running thread, which will cause handler not invoking, which will result in undisposed WaitHandle.

Comment: Ahh, that is your real problem. Maybe the waithandle should be a parameter in RunWork so that implementation can signal 'finished'?

Comment: Work completed is signalled by the **Completed** event.

Comment: Then my solution is sound. I assume you have exception handling in RunWork that guarantees that the Completed event is invoken in all circumstances?